# Retrieving the individual private keys in a VB.NET encryption example

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption, cryptography

I'm using this example from Microsoft Docs on creating a cryptographic application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/walkthrough-creating-a-cryptographic-application

The application allows me to encrypt a file and export a public key, which allows me to encrypt a text file, and it works.
The application also has a decryption feature which uses the generated ASM keypair to decrypt it (the documentation has more info).

The application only exports a Public Key in a .txt file but I would also like it to export a private key which can be shared to decrypt. How would I be able to retrieve and export the private key so that I could use it do decrypt the file individually without having to obtain the full keypair, with only the private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...but I would also like it to export a private key which can be shared to decrypt.

The private key is not shared, only the public key! Before encryption, both sides first exchange their public keys. The sender side encrypts the message with the public key of the receiving side. The receiving side decrypts the encrypted message with its private key. In this scenario, private keys are not exchanged anywhere (hence the term *private*), see chapters *3.2*, *3.3* and *3.4* in [RSA (cyrptosystem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).

> How would I be able to retrieve and export the private key...

Technically, the export of the private key is possible. In RSA, the public key (fields *n*, *e*) is a subset of the private key (fields *n*, *e*, *d*, *p*, *q*, *d mod(p-1)*, *d mod(q-1)*, *(inverse of q) mod(p)*), i.e., the private key *implicitly* contains the public key as well, see the chapters *A.1.1 RSA Public Key Syntax* and *A.1.2 RSA Private Key Syntax* in [RFC8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017).

In the [linked example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/walkthrough-creating-a-cryptographic-application#exporting-a-public-key), [`RSA.ToXmlString(Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring?view=netcore-3.1) is used for the key export. `RSA.ToXmlString(Boolean)` allows you to control with the [boolean parameter value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring?view=netcore-3.1#parameters) whether the private key (i.e. all fields) is exported (*true*), or whether only the public key (i.e. only *n*, *e*) is exported (*false*). During export the fields are serialized into an XML.  Both keys exported in this way can be imported with [`RSA.FromXmlString(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.fromxmlstring?view=netcore-3.1).